How to run httpbin locally and integrate with Tyk Gateway?
I want to run httpbin locally and integrate it with my Tyk Gateway. So far I have a working Gateway and a working httpbin API which runs on :80
I used my working api definition for another api which runs online and tried to change the name, id and proxy in the following .json:
{
    "name": "httpbin",
    "api_id": "2",
    "use_keyless": true,
    "version_data": {
        "not_versioned": true,
        "versions": {
            "Default": {
                "name": "Default",
                "use_extended_paths": true
            }
        }
    },
    "proxy": {
        "listen_path": "/httpbin/",
        "target_url": "http://host.docker.internal:80",
        "strip_listen_path": true
    }
}

When starting the Tyk Gateway now and send requests to localhost:8080/httpbin/ I get:
{
   "error": "There was a problem proxying the request"
}

I already tried with localhost:80 as target_url but nothing seems to do the trick.
